# RNN LSTM Sentiment analysis model with low accuracy

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, sentiment-analysis

I have a dataset with 200000 samples.
I am using the train_test_split from Sklearn.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(50000,128, input_length=14))
model.add(LSTM(16, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(16, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.2))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_logarithmic_error', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I got a low accuracy = 0.39.

Can I know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding more fully connected layers between the LSTM and the last layer

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(50000,128, input_length=14))
model.add(LSTM(16, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(16, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
####model.add(Dense(10))####
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_logarithmic_error', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score -1):

Low is relative. How much accuracy do you expect, and which are your baseline model(s) for comparison?

Also, why did you pick these specific values for your hyper-parameters? Have you tried searching for optimal hyper-parameters?